# Is this operator closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider the linear operator $H$ with domain $D(H) = S(\mathbb R)\subset L^2(\mathbb R)$, where $S(\mathbb R)$ is Schwartz space, defined by
\begin{align}
  H\psi(x) = -ix^3\frac{d\psi}{dx}(x) -i \frac{d}{dx} (x^3\psi(x))
\end{align}
Is this operator closed?